# NSTableView cuts off content

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm building in content inside of a NSTableView, but when I compile and run, it cuts off the top half of all the content within the NSTableView.  I'm brand new to the Swift language so I am quite lost here.  I can provide further examples as necessary.  Is there something simple I am missing first or is this more specific to my use case?

Answer (score 0):

I can quickly give you a few directions to go looking for help.

Firstly the Apple Documentation for it. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html

You may note that there are essentially two ways of populating the table view, programmatically by implementing the methods of `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` protocols. And by using Cocoa Bindings. I recommend, as a beginner, to use the first option and look at either example code or videos that use these protocols.

Secondly, this may be just a UI issue in your storyboard, make sure your constraints are set properly. You may just have some weird behavior going on here with other views.

**Unfortunately, I cannot give you more help without code snippets or more information**